# How can I check if a user is an admin of a page without the manage_pages permission?

Tags: facebook

Is that possible? I don't actually want to manage their pages, I just want to know if they are an admin of the page so we can grant the user special permission in the Facebook application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook will send that piece of info when the admin land on your Page Tab inside the `signed_request` ([*reference*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs)):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST["signed_request"])) {
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);

    if (empty($data["page"]["admin"])) {
        echo "You are not an admin!";
    } else {
        echo "Welcome Admin!";
    }
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

?>
```

Comment: Excellent point! I need to be able to do it outside of the page tab as well though.

Comment: Be careful! If someone else add’s your app to their page, this code would recognize them as admin as well. You should also check if the page it’s called from is one of yours.